# Secure file transfer from many client partner networks to Azure

Tags: azure, encryption, cryptography, hsm

We are trying to provide easy but secured file transfer option to our partners, so they can send large files from their networks to our company network . There are many partners.
The intent is to ensure both : 1) Correct identification of partner and ensuring content has not changed after it was released from the source system( the typical digital signature aspect)  2) The data is encrypted so no man-in-the-middle can make sense out of it.

Current setup is very tedious and manual, it takes a lot of time to setup file transfer system as HSM is manually installed in the the network of the partner where partner private key is installed. Through our software, client machines use the key in the HSM to digitally sign the file and then the files are transferred through HTTPs.  Why HSM - as we need to be FIPS compliant and HSM is the most secured way .
There is lot of cost involved in hiring specialists who visit the partner premises to setup HSM with partner private key .

Now, the ask is to make it very simple for partners( something like simple web upload), yet keep it very secured (level of HSM).
The manual visit of specialist to partner premises to install HSM , is to be avoided.
And , Azure can be used as target platform for upload.

Looking for solution which can fit in the scenario.

Comment: This is a very broad question (even not about programming), this question may get downvoted and closed. You may try to ask in the information security section

Comment: Well, I'll keep my downvote in my pocket, but asking us to design an entire secure system is even a bit much for security.SE (or crypto.SE, you can take my word for that).

Answer (score 0):

This is more architectural question, not really programming, but let's try.

> 1. Correct identification of partner and ensuring content has not changed after it was released from the source system( the typical digital signature aspect)
> 2. The data is encrypted so no man-in-the-middle can make sense out of it.
>    Why HSM - as we need to be FIPS compliant and HSM is the most secured way .
>
> Now, the ask is to make it very simple for partners( something like simple web upload), yet keep it very secured (level of HSM). The manual visit of specialist to partner premises to install HSM , is to be avoided.

For safe and secured (signed) transfer we were using and proposing MFTP (managed file transfer), such as OFTP2 protocol. However, not every implementation supports HSM out of box. Yet you may keep it even simpler.

> The manual visit of specialist to partner premises to install HSM , is to be avoided.

So - at the end there are two options. Either the client will do the installation himself, or you the partners may use a Cloud HSM. There is no real reason why to use a specific product. Every larger cloud provider offers some sort of the HSM product (IBM, Azure, AWS, Google). I personally like the AWS HSM option as they are very clear about the pricing and the required infrastructure.

However - in the last few years even the default key services are getting FIPS140-2L2 or FIPS140-2L3 compliant (AWS KSM, Azure KeyVault, IBM KeyProtect, not sure about others). So if you're insisting on compliance, it's much easier and cheaper for the partners just to use the key management services (KMS, KeyVault) to sign the document hash, yet still providing the required level of security.

> Now, the ask is to make it very simple for partners( something like simple web upload), yet keep it very secured (level of HSM).

The partner needs to provide the file and the signature. To upload large files, for Azure I'd go for [SAS tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) (signed url). Your web app can provide a signed URL (url with as a sas token) to the authenticated client and the client will create and upload the file and the file signature. That way you can ensure level of authentication and integrity.

Without stating more constraints or requirements it would be just guessing. So I hope this helps too.